# How do I create an automated calculated column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Help me create a column, that shows the company's budget. Let's say we have three tables: Budget, Purchase, and Sale.

```
CREATE TABLE Budget (
ID int primary key identity(1,1) not null,
BudgetAmount float not null
);

CREATE TABLE PurchasingRawMaterials (
ID int primary key identity(1,1) not null,
RawMaterials int foreign key (Raw Materials) references RawMaterials (ID) not null,
Number int not null,
Price float not null,
Date date not null
);

CREATE TABLE ProductSales (
ID int primary key identity(1,1) not null,
Products int foreign key (Products) references FinishedProducts (ID) not null,
Number int not null,
Price float not null,
Date date not null
);
```

When we selling products, the budget increases, when buying raw materials, it decreases. That is, automatically when you add a value to these tables, the budget value immediately changes.

Comment: I guess you need AFTER INSERT trigger for the tables PurchasingRawMaterials  and ProductSales

Comment: @Sergey can you write an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Inserted** table inside the Trigger to find the recently inserted record and update the Price amount with the Budget Table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_PurchasingRawMaterials
ON PurchasingRawMaterials
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN

UPDATE B
SET BudgetAmount=BudgetAmount-inserted.Price
FROM Budget B
INNER JOIN inserted On B.ID=inserted.RawMaterials

END
GO

CREATE TRIGGER TRG_ProductSales
ON ProductSales
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN

UPDATE B
SET BudgetAmount=BudgetAmount+inserted.Price
FROM Budget B
INNER JOIN inserted On B.ID=inserted.Products

END
```

Comment: What is B? And explain this line to me: INNER JOIN inserted On B.ID=inserted.Products
And about this: FROM Budget B

Comment: It's just an alias name for the table 'Budget'. @Asel